# Since when does PHP autocast integer to float?

Tags: php, syntax

```
echo 1/3;
```

I was expecting the above to output `0`, but in fact **PHP** is smart enough to output `0.33333333333333`

Since when does PHP start to behave like this?

Comment: It doesn't, but it's casting the result of a mathematical expression (1/3) to a float

Comment: there are cool answers to your question(s), accept one! ;)

Answer (score 12):

It has always behaved like this. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

> The division operator ("/") returns a
>   float value unless the two operands
>   are integers (or strings that get
>   converted to integers) and the numbers
>   are evenly divisible, in which case an
>   integer value will be returned.

Comment: @wamp: yes, but 1 is not evenly divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't a strongly typed language. It does things like that all the time.

As far as I know, php was designed like this from the beginning.

Comment: The most crazy thing is the autocast from strings to integer, if the string only consists of numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is the expected behaviour.

If you want an integer, force a cast:

```
echo (int)(1/3);
```

Comment: Isn't `1` the same as `(int)1` ?